# Load tests without rebuilding the whole project

Tags: maven, gatling

I'd like to run my gatling tests without having to rebuild the whole project.

In my maven-gatling-plugin configuration I have the following

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>load-testing</id>
        <phase>integration-test</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>execute</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
            <simulationClass>maven.integration.MySimu</simulationClass>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Is there a phase I can use that doesn't build the project?

Comment: How do you run maven ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution for me was to put all my simulations inside an independant project (as opposed to having them inside the project I wanted to test)

Then I could execute the simulations with `mvn gatling:execute`